# How do I return a reference type as JSON in AspNetCore 3.0 preview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im trying to return a list of students in one of my controllers but I always get a 406 Not Acceptable. I have a second test controller which just returns *Ok(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });* and it responds with proper JSON.

Example Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : Controller {
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        IEnumerable<Student> students = await _repository.GetAllStudentsAsync();
        return Ok(students);
    }
}
```

The students list contains one entry and looks generally fine.

The project uses [AspNetCore App 3.0 preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/3.0.0-preview-19075-0444) and [AspNetCore NewtonsoftJson 3.0 preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.0.0-preview-19075-0444) because the JSON generation was removed from the main AspNetCore package.

I added

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

in my Startup.cs. Is there anything else missing?

Update 1:

If I return the students with *return Json(students);* it returns a json result with no 406, but it does not work with Ok(...).

Comment: Whats `GetAllStudentsAsync` return?

Comment: I can't see assets variable is been set anywhere in the code snippet. What are you actually returning?

Comment: He wouldn't get a 406 in this case, he'd just get a compile error. I think it's just a mistake in the copy/paste to stackoverflow.

Comment: Also in your MvcOption's do you have RespectBrowserAcceptHeader set to true, this turns on 406 unacceptable processing on. By default Asp Net Core will spit out json unless that value is true. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#content-negotiation-process

Comment: Have you tried updated the NuGet packages to the latest versions? The ones you have linked to were updated a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @Unavi, Can you please rename your method From GetAll() to Get() and check one more? Not sure about that but you should try once.

Comment: @Unavi the error complains about your request, not the payload. 406 is a request error. `GetAll` never gets executed. How are you calling it, what does the URL look like?

Comment: @Unavi if you check [what 406 means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406), it seems you asked for the wrong content type or encoding in the `Accept-` headers

Comment: @GlennWatson I expanded the var to show the response

Comment: @Unavi post your *request* code and content. How did you try to call that method? With your own code? Postman? curl? Did you try debugging the code, does `GetAll()` get called?

Comment: @GlennWatson I didn't set RespectBrowserAcceptHeader. Even when I send application/json with the header in Postman it returns 406.

Comment: @SimplyGed I have the latest package, I referenced the wrong link in my question. Fixed it in the question.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Tried that and didn't change. The naming doesn't affect the request I think.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When I set a break point it gets hit and it runs to return Ok(...) fine. I called the method with Postman and Chrome. Url: http://localhost:65271/api/user with and without Accept application/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had overridden the [Produces("application/json")] in one of the child controllers with [Produces("application/xml")]. Because I did not provide any xml Formatters, I got the 406.

Originally I tried around xml/json a few times because I was missing                 services.AddMvc()**.AddNewtonsoftJson();** from [AspNetCore NewtonsoftJson 3.0 preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.0.0-preview-19075-0444). It is needed because Newtonsoft.Json was removed from Asp Core in version 3.0 ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/10/29/a-first-look-at-changes-coming-in-asp-net-core-3-0/)).